# SQL Calculating Aggregated Totals-To-Date

Tags: sql-server, performance, view, aggregate

Suppose I have a table, `my_table`, with 2 columns: `date`, `value`.
And I want to calculate a 3rd column: `aggregated_value_year_to_date`.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
SELECT date,
       value,
       (SELECT SUM(value)
            FROM my_table AS Match
            WHERE Match.Year = Base.Year
              AND Match.date < Base.date) AS aggregated_value_year_to_date

  FROM table AS Base
```

Are there any better options?
Particularly is there any options that have better performance when `my_table` is actually a moderately complex view?

This query is re-evaluating the underlying view repeatedly which is getting rather expensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the cumulative sum window function:

```
SELECT date, value,
       (sum(value) over (partition by year order by date) -  
        value
       ) as aggregated_value_year_to_date
FROM table t;
```

The `over` clause includes the current row by default.  This version subtracts the value on the current row to get the sum through the previous value.

An alternative to the `-` is:

```
SELECT date, value,
       (sum(value) over (partition by year
                               order by date
                               row between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
       ) as aggregated_value_year_to_date
FROM table t;
```

Both of these assume that there is (at most) one row per date.  It uses a convenient shortcut instead of a windowing clause.

Comment: Ironically next thing I do with the aggregated result is to add today's value to it (so that I have the row with it's start and end total) to the `-` is no problem at all :)

Comment: btw, typo `FROM Table t` should be `FROM t` (or `FROM my_table` in my example)

Comment: I believe this to be the correct answer ... I'll leave the question open for a couple of days though, just, on general principle. Feel free to message me if I forget to come back and do so.